# Looking to create column of "rank arrays" based on another column of Array(Float) type

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rank

Here is my dataset:

```
score  
[0.3, 0.5]
[0.1, 0.6, 0.7]
```

Desired Dataset:

```
score            rank 
[0.3, 0.5]      [1, 2]
[0.1, 0.6, 0.7] [1, 2, 3]
```

This is my initial attempt:

```
df_upd = df.withColumn("rank", F.array([F.lit(i) for i in range(1, F.size("score") + 1)]))
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got Column.

I'm wondering if there are any concise ways to do this or will I have to explode `df` and then create a rank column using Window functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want just create a sequence from `1` to `size(score)`, you can use `sequence` function for that:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([([0.3, 0.5],), ([0.1, 0.6, 0.7],)], ["score"])

df.withColumn("rank", F.expr("sequence(1, size(score))")).show()

#+---------------+---------+
#|          score|     rank|
#+---------------+---------+
#|     [0.3, 0.5]|   [1, 2]|
#|[0.1, 0.6, 0.7]|[1, 2, 3]|
#+---------------+---------+
```